# BlueprintJS: How to close a select popup on click outside?

Tags: blueprintjs

In the official documentation, the select popup dropdown has the behavior that it gets closed automatically when the user clicks anywhere outside the popup. This can be seen here:

https://blueprintjs.com/docs/#select/select-component

In my own application, I cannot seem to replicate this behavior. For me, the popup always remains open even if the user clicks somewhere outside the popup.

How can I achieve the same behavior as in the example shown in the documentation? There doesn't seem to be a property which directly controls this.

I tried to find a property which deals with the "close on click outside" behavior, but either I'm too blind to see it or it is controlled indirectly by something else. The docs page doesn't mention this detail at all.

Answer (score 0):

What versions of blueprintjs core and select are you using?

The problem can be deduced from this bug report on their Github repo: https://github.com/palantir/blueprint/issues/5781

I had this issue as well until I upgraded to the latest `blueprintjs/core` version (5.9.1 in my case) so it would work with my `blueprintjs/select` 5.1.1 version.